# Как правильно указать путь до модели в populate mongoose (nest, graphql, mongodb)?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, graphql

Я использую `nestjs`, `graphql`, `mongoose`.

Получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Schema hasn't been registered for model "languageLearningMaterial".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "languageLearningMaterial".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
```

Мне нужно в сервисе сделать `populate`, чтобы достать из БД данные из `LanguageLearningMaterial`, но не выходит из-за ошибки. Много чего перепробовал так и не получилось выполнить populate.

```
//language-learning-material.schema
export type LanguageLearningMaterialDocument = LanguageLearningMaterial &
    Document

@ObjectType()
@Schema()
export class LanguageLearningMaterial {
    @Field(() => ID)
    _id: string

    @Field()
    @IsString()
    @Prop({ type: String })
    videoCdnFileURL: string

    @Field()
    @IsString()
    @Prop({ type: String })
    subtitleCdnFileURL: string
}

export const LanguageLearningMaterialSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(
    LanguageLearningMaterial
)
```

```
//user.schema
@ObjectType()
@Schema()
export class User {
    @Field(() => ID)
    _id: string

    @Field(() => [LanguageLearningMaterial], {
        nullable: true,
        defaultValue: [],
    })
    @Prop({
        type: [
            { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'languageLearningMaterial' },
        ],
    })
    languageLearningMaterial: LanguageLearningMaterial[]
}

export type UserDocument = User & Document

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User)
```

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>,
        @InjectModel(LanguageLearningMaterial.name)
        private languageLearningMaterialModel: Model<LanguageLearningMaterialDocument>
    ) {}

    async createLanguageLearningMaterial(
        userId: string,
        input: CreateLanguageLearningMaterialInput
    ): Promise<User> {
        const user = await this.userModel.findById(userId)
        const languageLearningMateria =
            await this.languageLearningMaterialModel.create(input)

        user.languageLearningMaterial.push(languageLearningMateria._id)
        return (await user.save()).populate({
            path: 'languageLearningMaterial',
        })
    }
}
```

```
//user.module

@Module({
    imports: [
        forwardRef(() => AuthModule),
        MongooseModule.forFeature([
            { name: User.name, schema: UserSchema },
            {
                name: LanguageLearningMaterial.name,
                schema: LanguageLearningMaterialSchema,
            },
        ]),
    ],
    providers: [UserService, UserResolver],
    exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Comment: Не уверен, но в `user.schema` в `ref` насколько я помню, регистр важен. Попробуйте написать `"LanguageLearningMaterial"`, вместо `"languageLearningMaterial"`.